# Error when running npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer@0.20

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

This statement is to install a **useful utility for generating application assets**. The installation is on Ubuntu running in a VM on a Windows 10 laptop. The script ran to completion but there were two ERR messages together in the output. **Are these messages significant or can I ignore them?**

> Messages:
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@8.11.4 (node v-57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN storage.googleapis.com:443**

Answer (score 0):

the issue was one of getting out to download (initially) the pre-compiled binaries, as posted above. The fallback is to compile locally. So the question is - is it working?

The error about EAI_AGAIN (this is a DNS lookup time out error) means it is a network connectivity / proxy related / routing error, to get out from your VM to www.

Comment: Thank you Paul. That has answered the question. The install has worked with some local compiles. So I assume the 2nd msg EAI_AGAIN is as a result of not being able to get out to download the pre compiled binaries.